# Why does the statet eclipse plugin crash upon updating the envrionment index with java 1.7.0?

Tags: java, eclipse, r, statet

Running R in Eclipse using the statet plugin results in a crash when I choose to update the environment index (necessary for the popup help) but only if run with java 1.7.0.
Versions: R 2.15.2x64, statet 3.1.2, rj 1.1.

When run with an older jvm (1.6.0_31) the environment index can be updated succesfully.

I have got a workaround now, but it would be nice to know the cause.

Comment: Perhaps you could drop a line to the StatET mailing list. Another workaround would be to use RTerm console instead of RJ.

Answer (score 0):

What was the workaround that you mentioned? I'm having similar problems on Windows, x64, with Java 7 and R 3.0.3. My own workaround was to specify Java 1.6 in Eclipse config. Thanks.